# How to pass a variable number to an Apps Script Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I cannot get this line of code to work where `nowts` is the number 12 for example obtained from a ui:

```
spreadsheet.getRange("L"&(nowts+1):"L"&(nowts+2)).clearContent();
```

I am trying to clear the contents in the range L13:L14
Whee am I getting the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the `getRange` is wrong. Replace

```
"L"&(nowts+1):"L"&(nowts+2)
```

(missing `&` and `:` should be inside a pair of quotes)

by

```
"L"&(nowts+1)&":L"&(nowts+2)
```